# Find CFG for $L=\{0^i1^j2^k\mid i\ne j\vee j\ne k,\ i,j,k>0\}$

Tags: context-free-grammar

I am trying to find context free grammar for the following language

> $$L=\{0^i1^j2^k\mid i\ne j\vee j\ne k,\ i,j,k>0\}$$

I tried to write the following rules: \begin{align*}S&\to S_1C\mid S_2C\mid AS_3\mid AS_4 \\ S_1&\to 0A\mid 0S_11 \\ S_2&\to 1B\mid 0S_21 \\ S_3&\to 1B\mid 1S_32 \\ S_4&\to 2C\mid 1S_42 \\ A&\to 0A\mid \varepsilon \\ B&\to 1B\mid \varepsilon \\ C&\to 2C\mid \varepsilon \end{align*} but the solution does not satisfy the condition $i,j,k>0$. How should I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was easier to start from scratch, though I think that we’re following the same basic idea.

$$\begin{align*}
S&\to S_{i<j}C\mid S_{i>j}C\mid AS_{j<k}\mid AS_{j>k}\\
S_{i<j}&\to XB\\
S_{i>j}&\to AX\\
S_{j<k}&\to YC\\
S_{j>k}&\to BY\\
X&\to 0X1\mid 01\\
Y&\to 1Y2\mid 12\\
A&\to 0A\mid 0\\
B&\to 1B\mid 1\\
C&\to 2C\mid 2\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: The word '0' can be generated using these rules, but it is not in L...

Comment: @Galc127: Forgot about that condition. I’ve revised it very slightly so that at least one of each letter will be generated, I *think* without losing anything that we want.